# OSB - Split-Join with JMS

Tags: weblogic, soa, osb

I have a proxy that reads a message from a queue and, using only a business, I must put the message iteratively in four topic.

I can't use a Xquery with topic endpoint because I have different environments and this endpoints are different in any environment.

It's possible to use Split-Join with JMS?

Thank's!!

Answer (score 0):

Split-joins are a parallel alternative to ForEach loops, so if you could do it in an (unrolled) ForEach loop, then you can do it in a SplitJoin.

Comment: I'm getting the next error: Multiple messages with QName xxx found. Messages must be unique.

Is this error produced because I'm using the same WSDL?

Comment: Yes, that's a known bug in how split joins are implemented (at least it was in 11g, don't know about 12c). If you have the opportunity, use something like GenericParallel instead, which wraps split joins in a framework that avoids bugs like this.